# param not found: in rails4 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Error while using rails 4 strong parameters.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /questions
param not found: question
```

I have a `Question model` and `questions controller`. The questions table has `content column`

this is what is contained in the `questions controller`

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @questioner = Questioner.new(questioner_params)
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
  end

  def edit
    @question = find(params[:id])
    raise "Question Not edited!" unless @question
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)

    respond_to do |wants|
      if @question.save
        flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully posted the questions!'
        wants.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
        wants.xml  { render :xml => @question, :status => :created, :location => @question }
      else
        flash[:error] = "Please review the problems below."
        wants.html { redirect_to(questions_path) }
        wants.xml  { render :xml => @question.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using questioner_params but it's not defined anywhere. Besides, when you're displaying the index action, you're not setting any params. You only need to input the params when the user click submit which should go to the create action.

```
def index
  @question = Question.new
  @questioner = Questioner.new
end
```

Comment: but now i got undefined method `question' error. plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101512/undefined-method-model-name-question-for-rails-4 and help where possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your controller's index action:

```
def index
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  @questioner = Questioner.new(questioner_params)
end
```

First, there's no `questioner_params`.  More importantly, there are no params for the index action - look at the output of `rake routes`  Try defining `@questions = Question.all` instead of `@question = Question.new` for the index action since index is used to show the collection of all questions.

Check this out, too, it's a good read and really helpful when you're just beginning:

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
```

Comment: I have a 2 forms in the index page. one using question and the other questioner

Answer (score -1):

Where is def show ? It seems very important in the questions controller.

try

def show 
@question = Question.find(params[:id]) 
end

Comment: David I appreciate the answer but show action is used to display only further details on a single question.