# undefined method `model_name_question' for #..Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am getting this error after submitting the form:(in the index page)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@quiz, html: {class: 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages_question' %>
            <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have `question` model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :question, presence: true

    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :questioner
end
```

and questions controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @quiz = Question.new
    @questioner = Questioner.new
  end

  def new
    @quiz = Question.new(quiz_params)
  end

  def show
    @quiz = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @quiz = find(params[:id])
    raise "Question Not edited!" unless @quiz
  end

  def create
    @quiz = Question.new(quiz_params)

    if @quiz.save
      flash[:success] = 'You have successfully posted the questions!'
      redirect_to questions_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please review the problems below."
      # render 'new'
      redirect_to questions_path
    end
  end

  private

    def quiz_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content, :answered, :questioner_id, :category_id)
    end
end
```

what could b the problem? 
in the rails server I have this:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

    NoMethodError - undefined method `question' for #<Question:0x0000000433dfc0>:
      activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may potentially be related to this validation line

```
validates :question, presence: true
```

It assumes your Question model has a `:question` attribute. In other words, makes sure there is a proper `question` database column in the `questions` database table.

If this is not the case, fix the either the table or the validation accordingly.